# Python complexity reference?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Is there any Python complexity reference? In [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), for example, for many functions (such as [std::array::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) or [std::array::fill](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill)) there's a **complexity** section which describes their running complexity, in terms of *linear in the size of the container* or *constant*.

I would expect the same information to appear in the python website, perhaps, at least for the CPython implementation. For example, in the [list reference](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), in `list.insert` I would expect to see **complexity: linear**; I know this case (and many other container-related operations) is covered [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), but many other cases are not. Here are a few examples:

- What is the complexity of `tuple.__le__`? It seems like when comparing two tuples of size `n`, `k`, the complexity is about `O(min(n,k))` (however, for small `n`'s it looks different).
- What is the complexity of [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)? It appears to be `O(n)`. It also appears that the complexity of [`random.randint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) is `O(1)`.
- What is the complexity of the `__format__` method of strings? It appears to be linear in the size of the input string; however, it also grows when the number of **relevant** arguments grow (compare `("{0}"*100000).format(*(("abc",)*100000))` with `("{}"*100000).format(*(("abc",)*100000))`).

I'm aware that (a) each of these questions may be answered by itself, (b) one may look at the code of these modules (even though some are written in C), and (c) StackExchange is not a python mailing list for user requests. So: this is not a doc-feature request, just a question of two parts:

1. Do you know if such a resource exists?
2. If not, do you know what is the place to ask for such, or can you suggest why I don't need such?

Comment: I believe somewhere in the documentation is stated that *all* collections in the stdlib or built-in provide O(1) `__len__` methods. Also note, regarding the `random` module, the documentation specifically links to some articles about PRNG, so I'd assume that these articles make pretty precise statements about complexities.

Comment: I am not aware of a resource like that, this seems like a good fit for python-ideas!

Comment: I suspect you're going to get a lot of unsatisfying upvotes and an implicit "no" answer.

Comment: This slightly looks like an off-topic question, as OP expects an `off-site resource`

Comment: I don't think we're going to get spam for this, and for people to give opinionated answers about their favorite Python time-complexity documentation, we would have to first find at least one answer. I don't think the basis for that close reason really applies.

Comment: Ask your "very good" question on Quora :). Even if there is no answer atleast somebody will get an idea to have an extra line on time/space complexities of the standard library functions in the documentation  just as cppreference does. However I vote to repoen your question. +1.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to write one ;)

Comment: It's virtually impossible to measure the complexity of small things; you end up having to take account of all sorts of constant-time effects that you can ignore with large input values.

Comment: Also, for my money the right place for these things to be documented would be in main Python documentation, though the wording would need to be careful. (Is a conforming implementation constrained to have a particular complexity class, or is that just a feature of a particular exemplar?) Where things are absent, you should submit patches to change that; that's one of the main ways that open source software documentation gets improved.

Answer (score 5):

CPython is pretty good about its algorithms, and the time complexity of an operation is usually just the best you would expect of a good standard library.

For example:

Tuple ordering has to be *O(min(n,m))*, because it works by comparing element-wise.

`random.shuffle` is *O(n)*, because that's the complexity of the modern Fisher–Yates shuffle.

`.format` I *imagine* is linear, since it only requires one scan through the template string.  As for the difference you see, CPython might just be clever enough to cache the same format code used twice.

The docs do mention time complexity, but generally only when it's not what you would expect — for example, because a `deque` is implemented with a doubly-linked list, it's [explicitly mentioned](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) as having `O(n)` for indexing in the middle.

Would the docs benefit from having time complexity called out everywhere it's appropriate?  I'm not sure.  The docs generally present builtins by what they should be *used for* and have implementations optimized for those use cases.  Emphasizing time complexity seems like it would either be useless noise or encourage developers to second-guess the Python implementation itself.

Comment: It also ties their hands with respect to altering implementation. This is the reason, for example, why C++'s standard avoided specifying the time complexity of the ``size`` method to be *O(1)* for standard containers like ``vector`` until recently (which is why many CS courses still teach you to always test for ``vector.empty()`` rather than ``vector.size() == 0``). Remember, even **CPython** is limited by the underlying C standard lib implementations, many of which themselves don't specify hard complexity constraints and instead leave it up to implementation.

Comment: it also ties the hands of _alternative_ implementations — but then, it could arguably be a good thing to enforce that a correct Python implementation is _O(1)_ for, say, set membership.  i think the use-case approach probably does a good enough job of that though, and indeed leaves some breathing room for alternatives to do better.

Comment: I would hope we don't insist on O(1) for set membership. I don't know of any data structures for sets that can guarantee that bound in the worst case. And some really good implementations are explicitly O(log n).